# Installing Oracle Linux in bare metal

Tags: bootable-media, oracle-linux

I want to install Oracle Linux Version 6.6 (to begin with) in bare metal (that is wiping out the existing OS and keep this as the primary OS installed.)

I downloaded the .iso images from oracle website and before the download begins it gives couple of .iso files. See the diagram below:

[image]

I am not sure why we have these many files to download? I want to install this OS using USB (my Laptop don't have CD/DVD).

In past I have successfully installed Ubuntu using USB. When I download Ubuntu, there it downloads only one .iso files and using unetbootin-windows software I created the Bootable USB, from which i was able to install Ubuntu.

Now, I am trying to do the same for Oracle Linux, but I am not sure which files /.iso should  I chose for creating the bootable USB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only the `Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 for x86_64 (64 Bit)` image.

The other files:

- Source: Contains the source files for the programs you find compiled. You do not have to worry about this. They just have to provide this for legal reasons. (See GPL, etc.)
- Boot ISO image: While I am not familiar with Oracle Linux's structure, I am pretty sure this is a minimalistic boot image. One you put on a bootable media, boot it up, and then the installer downloads the files during the install.
- Boot ISO UEK image: Same thing, but with the "Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release" buzzword kernel included. Don't worry, the install image - the big one - contains both kernels I am pretty sure.

**How to create bootable image on Windows:**

- https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
- https://rufus.akeo.ie/
- https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/

Which one to pick? Try them out. :)
For Linux I usually use the first one. For Rescue disc, I use Xboot.
But all of them should work.

**How to create bootable image on Linux:**

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

**What if my USB will not boot even though I followed every step?**
You have to "clean" the drive off.

- Windows: [How do I format a usb drive on a PC that was formatted on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/274687/how-do-i-format-a-usb-drive-on-a-pc-that-was-formatted-on-a-mac)
- Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/185815/how-do-i-clear-everything-data-viruses-from-a-thumbdrive

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed info. I am going to follow the steps that you provided and hopefully get it right. Thanks a ton!